# OpenCV video capture - output even potentially corrupt frames

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, udp, h.264

In FFmpeg, there is a flag "output_corrupt" that allows the command to output even corrupted frames. I am sending h264 stream to a server where its first few frames are corrupted. By setting "output_corrupt" flag in my FFmpeg command, I am able to view the live stream.
I can see the live stream by piping FFmpeg data to OpenCV VideoCapture (i.e. cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/stdin'))

Note: since my plan is to run CV algorithms on those frames, I need to be able to run it on OpenCV.

However, by not directly sending the data through VideoCapture, it unavoidably causes some latency issue.

The best scenario would be to just directly send the h264 stream to OpenCV VideoCapture (i.e. cv2.VideoCapture('udp://......'))
However, because of the corrupted frames, the OpenCV script gets stuck after a second.

Is there any way to run OpenCV VideoCapture such that it still outputs potentially corrupt frames?

Thank you.